# Display Image on a Canvas Pixel by Pixel with SWT

Tags: java, canvas, bitmap, swt

I am trying to read a BitMap pixel by Pixel (yet to be done), then display each Pixel on a Canvas in SWT.

Is this the proper way to display the pixels?

The following method seems to work but I am wondering if there are better options in Java SWT.  My input will be a lot of ARGB values, and I am wondering if this will be scalable.

```
public class ReadyBitMapDisplayAsPixels {
BufferedImage bitmapImage = null;

      private void createContents(Shell shell) {

            try {
                bitmapImage = ImageIO.read(new File("c:\\BMP\\Earth.bmp"));
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }

          shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

        // Create a canvas to draw on
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(shell, SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.NO_REDRAW_RESIZE | SWT.DOUBLE_BUFFERED);

        // Add a handler to do the drawing
        canvas.addPaintListener(new PaintListener() {
          public void paintControl(PaintEvent e) {
            // Get the canvas and its size
            Canvas canvas = (Canvas) e.widget;

            int height = bitmapImage.getHeight();
            int width = bitmapImage.getWidth();

            PaletteData palette=new PaletteData(0xff0000,0x00ff00,0x0000ff);
            ImageData imageData = new ImageData(width, height,24,palette);

            for (int h = 0; h<height; h++)
            {
                for (int w = 0; w<width; w++)
                {
                    int pixel = bitmapImage.getRGB(w, h);
                    //int alpha = (pixel >> 24) & 0xff;
                    int red = (pixel >> 16) & 0xff;
                    int green = (pixel >> 8) & 0xff;
                    int blue = (pixel) & 0xff;
                    imageData.setPixel(h, w, pixel);    
                }
            }

            //imageData = imageData.scaledTo(600, 500);
            Image image = ImageDescriptor.createFromImageData(imageData).createImage();
            e.gc.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
          }
        });
      }
      public static void main(String[] args) 
        {
            new ReadyBitMapDisplayAsPixels().run();
        }

         public void run() {
                Display display = new Display();
                Shell shell = new Shell(display);
                createContents(shell);
                shell.open();
                while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
                  if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                    display.sleep();
                  }
                }
                display.dispose();
              }

              /**
               * Creates the main window's contents
               * 
               * @param shell the main window
               */
```

}

Comment: Is there a reason you are using the AWT `BufferedImage` rather than the `SWT` `Image` which you can just draw directly on the canvas?

Comment: It is for demonstration purposes, at a later stage I will have raw ARGB values from a different source.  I am just using the BitMap file as a test source for Pixels

Comment: so - what is your question? is it possible to read a bitmap file? is this the correct way to display pixels? can you be specific?

Comment: @MartinFrank Displaying the Pixels.  The BitMap is just incidental as I need some quick and dirty source of pixels.